# How to read a binary field within a text file

Tags: c#, binary, streamreader

I have a fixed width text file that I am using streamreader/readline() to read at the moment.

There's one field that when I open in notepad++ looks like this

[NUL][NUL][NUL][SUB]

Everything else is normal text. I know this field is meant to be 4 characters and represents a count so should look like this '0001'

How can I read it and convert into '0001'

Comment: There's `BinaryReader` in .Net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what the "SUB" is meant to correspond to - but if it's read as U+0001, you could always use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    chars[i + index] = (int) chars[i + index] + '0';
}
```

(Assuming you have a `char[]` called `chars`, with the 4 bytes starting at `index`.)

The first thing to check is whether you actually read the characters properly to start with. It's frankly a bit dodgy to have a "text" file with binary data in to start with, but if it's only bytes 0-9, then in *most* encodings I'd expect that to correspond to U+0000 to U+0009.

Comment: +1 I would think it might be a binary file contains some readable text.

Comment: Right now I'm extracting information by doing line.substrings on my line.readLine(). Do you mean I should convert those 4 chars into char[] before applying the above?

Comment: Oh I gave it a go and now outputting 0000, 000J and 0009. 0000 when all 4 are NULs which is correct I think, but I think the J and 9 are incorrect, this is where I get the SUBs and SOHs in notepad++

Comment: Looks like it works for 0001,0002, just some of those other 9s and Js that don't make any sense. I'm not sure if it's because the data is bad or it's meant to be something different. :|

Comment: @muddy: I think you should look at this in a binary file editor so that you know *exactly* what bytes are present.

Comment: Where the J pops up the hex is 1a and 9 is 09. I'm not really sure how I'm meant to interpret this.

Comment: @muddy: That's your first task then: understanding the data. You can't write code when you don't know what it's meant to do.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet I understand the data field is meant to represent numbers but this doesn't look like it'll work out, unless there are other ways to convert it into a number? Will go back to the source to see why it's like that.